# Find the nearest value in a column of grouped data, and then their corresponding rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a data.frame and the value 5.2

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6)+0.1, treat = c(rep('high',6), rep('low',6)))
df
my.val = 5.2
```

And I would like to find the nearest value in column 'x' to my value, and then the rows they are in.
Without grouping the data, I would use something like:

```
which(abs(df$x-my.val)==min(abs(df$x-my.val)))
#[1] 5 11
```

But how do you do this with a grouped table (in this case grouping by 'treat')?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(treat) %>% which(abs(df$x-my.val)==min(abs(df$x-my.val)))
Error in which(., abs(df$x - my.val) == min(abs(df$x - my.val))) : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Note: This is a simplified example. I have 45 groups in the original data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `which` should be inside the `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_by(treat) %>%
      summarise(i = which.min(abs(x - my.val)))
```

Or if we have multiple element in 'my.val'

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
    group_by(treat) %>%
    summarise(i = map_int(my.val, ~ which.min(abs(x - .x))))
```

---

Or may use `findInterval` as well

```
df %>%
    group_by(treat) %>% 
    summarise(i = findInterval(my.val, x))
```

Comment: Any idea how to use a different value for each group? e.g. my.val = c(1.2, 5.2)?

Comment: @Tom you may still use the `findInterval(my.val, x)` as long it is sorted

Comment: Thanks. I had success by creating a new data.frame with my.vals and 'treat' in it and then joinging it on i.e. df %>%  right_join(.,new.df, by = 'treat') %>% group_by(treat) %>% dplyr::summarise(row = which.min(abs(x- my.val)))

Comment: @Tom I meant the `findInerval` one if you need the first option, `summarise(i = map_int(my.val, ~ which.min(abs(x - .x))))`